# What is the purpose of the HTML attribute data-sheets-userformat?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

I am writing a script to migrate a WordPress site to a custom CMS. Within some of the post content there is some HTML that I don't understand.

What is the purpose of the data-sheets-userformat attribute?
`data-sheets-userformat='[null,null,14781,[null,2,"@",1], ...`

Comment: You'd have to talk to the author since that's just a custom data attribute and can be used for anything. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: I'm noticing the same weird stuff on my Wordpress site. No idea where it comes from. If anyone finds out, please let us know!